# css3 border image

Tags: html, css

I have four separate images each of 20px by 20px, I want to show each image on each border-side. any code snippet? My target platforms are FF 3.6+ and Safari 5+.

Using css3 and html5.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
/* Shorthand */
border-image:url('top.png') url('right.png') url('bottom.png') url('left.png');
```

Or the long way:

```
/* Long way */
border-top-image:url('...');
border-right-image:url('...');
border-bottom-image:url('...');
border-left-image:url('...');
```

Comment: It does not show any border in FF, I think u need prefixes like -moz but I am not sure what is the correct syntax

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem possible to use more than one image for the `border-image` attribute.

However, you can still use `border-image`, you'll just need to create an image with all four sides in one.

Look at the example here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-images

`border-image` takes the url for the image, and then four sizes, how much it should slice of the image to use.
The first value is used for the upper lefthand corner, the second for the upper righthand side, and so on.
Using

```
border-image: url("border.png") 20 20 20 20 repeat;
```

will chop of the upper left 20x20 pixels for the upper left of the div, det upper right 20x20 for the upper right of the div and so on.